# Why is my VBA code not downloading all files from the folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a code to pull files from Sharepoint and then downloading them to a local folder on the desktop. However, I notice that when there are large number of files to be downloaded, it only downloads partial files even though all files have a success export confirmation message. Please help!

```
Sub download_file()
    Dim dlpath, documenttosrc, filename As String
    Dim i As Double
    
    i = 11
    Do
        dlpath = Worksheets(CN.Name).Cells(i, 5).Value
        documenttosrc = Worksheets(CN.Name).Cells(i, 2).Value
        filename = Worksheets(CN.Name).Cells(i, 3).Value & ".pdf"
        
        URLDownloadToFile 0, documenttosrc, dlpath & filename, 0, 0
    
        Worksheets(CN.Name).Cells(i, 6).Value = " Download completed"

        i = i + 1  
    Loop Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    
    MsgBox ("Download done")
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `CN` in your code (it is not defined in your procedure)? Note that `Dim dlpath, documenttosrc, filename As String` only declares `filename As String` but the other variables `As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or it is `Variant` by default: `Dim dlpath As String, documenttosrc As String, filename As String`. Also `i` should be of type `Long` not `Double` because row numbers cannot be decimals but only integer numbers. • Please also include the code of `URLDownloadToFile` because the issue is probably in this code.

Comment: Hi, CN is the name of the worksheet that it is pulling the data from. Noted for the declare string. The code ```URLDownloadToFile``` ws copied from a website https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/download-files-with-vba-urldownloadtofile/

Comment: Please post the exact code you use, everything that is needed to understand your question needs to be in the question above. Links migth disappear after a while (or the website changes the code) and the question gets useless for future readers. Therefore please show use which code **you** used.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the [URLDownloadToFile function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)) has some return values that you don't vaidate.

- `S_OK`
  *The download started successfully.*
- `E_OUTOFMEMORY`
  *The buffer length is invalid, or there is insufficient memory to complete the operation.*
- `INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE`
  *The specified resource or callback interface was invalid.*

So you write `" Download completed"` in your cells all the time even if the download failed because you do not check if it failed or not.

So you need to get the return value of the function and validate it.

Declare the following constants that can be returned by the function.

```
Const S_OK As Long = 0
Const E_OUTOFMEMORY As Long = &H8007000E
Const INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE As Long = &H800C0002
```

And validate them like below:

```
Dim RetVal As Long
RetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0&, documenttosrc, dlpath & filename, 0&, 0&)

Select Case RetVal
    Case S_OK: 
        CN.Cells(i, 6).Value = " Download completed"
    Case E_OUTOFMEMORY: 
        CN.Cells(i, 6).Value = " The buffer length is invalid, or there is insufficient memory to complete the operation."
    Case INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE: 
        CN.Cells(i, 6).Value = " The specified resource or callback interface was invalid."
    Case Else:
        CN.Cells(i, 6).Value = " Unknown Error: " & RetVal
End Select
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Const S_OK As Long = 0
Private Const E_OUTOFMEMORY As Long = &H8007000E
Private Const INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE As Long = &H800C0002

Public Sub DownloadFiles()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = CN 'note that CN is already a worksheet so `Worksheets(CN.Name)` is not necessary you can directly use CN

    Dim i As Long
    i = 11
    Do
        Dim dlpath As String
        dlpath = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value

        Dim documenttosrc As String
        documenttosrc = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value

        Dim filename As String
        filename = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value & ".pdf"
        
        Dim RetVal As Long
        RetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0&, documenttosrc, dlpath & filename, 0&, 0&)
        
        Select Case RetVal
            Case S_OK: 
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = " Download completed"
            Case E_OUTOFMEMORY: 
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = " The buffer length is invalid, or there is insufficient memory to complete the operation."
            Case INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE: 
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = " The specified resource or callback interface was invalid."
            Case Else:
                ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = " Unknown Error: " & RetVal
        End Select 

        i = i + 1  
    Loop Until ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Or i = ws.Rows.Count
    
    MsgBox "Download done"
End Sub
```